# Android - how to kill camera activity started with startActivityForResult?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I started the camera activity from my app with this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(temp_file));
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and when the user clicks a notification icon i want to terminate the app using

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(0); //canceling the notification
System.exit(0);
```

from the parent activity. but the camera activity stays on and ready to take another picture.
how do i kill the camera from the parent app?
thanks.

Comment: you have to implement onActivtyResult method in calling activity because ince the camera pic is taken it will come to onActivityresult method then you can cancel it

Comment: i did implement it but that's not the problem. i want to terminate the camera activity from my activity without taking a picture

Comment: Have you tried calling `finishActivity(CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)`?

Comment: Have you tried to listen for the `activityPaused()` event and safely close the camera: `camera.stopPreview(); camera.release();` ?

Comment: @sam_c good one, thats the answer! (using the CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)

Comment: @sam_c I did, when I do that it seems that the camera is terminated in the finishActivity(CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE); but then comes back to life on System.exit(0);

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: @sam_c I am calling it right after calling the `mNotificationManager.cancel(0);` in the `onCreate` method of the parent activity. when I added the `finishActivity(CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)` it was between the two calls.

Comment: Instead of calling `System.exit(0)` have you tried just calling `finish()` on the parent activity after you explicitly finish the camera activity?

Comment: @sam_c yes I did, same result - the application exits but the camera flashes off then back on and remains active

Comment: Have you tried calling `finishActivity(CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)` again in the `onDestroy()` method of the parent activity? This might work to clean everything up on the way out of the main activity.